# Jython cant get eval output as String

Tags: java, jython

Im having an issue using Jython, I wish to capture the output of the eval function:

```
Object Pyoutput = pyEngine.eval("print('Hello World')");
System.out.println(Pyoutput.toString());
```

This was how i thought it could be done, but instead turns into a reference to the object. After some googling i found ways only to access specific variables etc that have been previously evaluated.

I have also tried exec:

```
interp.exec("print("hello world")");
```

But this cannot be assigned to a variable as its type is void. So my question is, is it possible to recover the entire output of eval or exec into a Java string so it can be displayed in another text field?

Comment: `eval("print("Hello World"))` does not compile. It should be `eval("print('Hello World')")`.

Comment: ah thanks no idea how that happend, corrected now :)

Comment: What do you mean by "but instead turns into a reference to the object"? What exactly is the output from `System.out.println(Pyoutput.toString());`?

Comment: `print` is a statement that does not return anything. In Python, it would not make sense to do `x = print("Hello world")`.

Comment: it previously returned a java object reference ID, but after re-running it now to paste here it caused an error instead:  Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: im not looking for it to return anything, i wish to have it execute the command and whatever python prints to the console as a result of eval, have it print to a java textbox instead or store it in a string

Comment: `Pyoutput` is `null` so it makes sense that `Pyoutput.toString()` results in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: OK so how can i retrieve the results of eval as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pyoutput` in the question is `null` (`print` does not return anything), so `Pyoutput.toString()` results in a `NullPointerException`.

It works with an expression that yields a value. The following program prints `6`.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine pyEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
    Object Pyoutput = pyEngine.eval("2*3");
    System.out.println(Pyoutput.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: OK that answer the question how to get the result from eval, but how can I get the entire terminal output. I.e for the print statement how could I capture the output of the print or everything that would normally be output I'm the terminal? For my example, how could l capture the output hello world and anything else that was output as the result of running the script?

Comment: You could assign whatever it is that you want to print to a variable (`pyEngine.eval("x = 'Hello world'");`), print it, and then retrieve the variable via `pyEngine.get(x)`. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Sort of. My intention is to embed a python interpreter in my program and allow users to code python from it, so I was hoping to just figure a way to write standard python and print the result of running the script to a textbox in my Java program. So I need a way to allow any regular python code to run and then print the result/output that would normally be in the command line/interpreter after running the script. Including pribts, expressions etc...pretty much everything..

Comment: OK, I understand (sort of...). I think you should post a new question if you need more help with this.